# How to use default style of Google Maps info windows with content security policy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps-api-3, content-security-policy

I am using the Google Maps Javascript API on a site with a Content Security Policy that does not allow inline CSS.

Before implementing the CSP, the info windows were styled nicely. After implementing the CSP, the info windows are not styled at all, because the Google Maps Javascript API uses inline CSS.

I am open to any solution that will get the info windows looking the way they used to.

The strategy I have attempted is to get the inline style that the Google Maps API has added to each element, then apply that style via jQuery. In theory, this should work because [jQuery's css() method does not use inline CSS](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/02/implementing-content-security-policy/):

> It’s worth mentioning that if style properties are updated via
>   JavaScript directly, then you won’t have a problem. For example,
>   jQuery’s css() method is fine because it updates style properties
>   directly under the covers.

Following is a minimal reproducible example.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/test.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/test.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-wrapper">
            <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#map-wrapper {
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 95%;
    width: 600px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
//on page load, call the function to initialize the map
$(function($) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initialize&key=yourKeyHere";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
});

//function to initialize the map
function initialize() {

    //construct the map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
        fullscreenControl: false,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
        scaleControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
    });

    //center the map
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng('34.4270881', '-117.57501819999999');
    map.setCenter(latLng);
    map.fitBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(latLng));

    //info window
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latLng, map: map, title: 'marker title'});
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) { return function() {
        infoWindow.setContent("foobar");
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', applyStyles(document.getElementById("map-wrapper")));
    }})(marker, i));
}

//function to get inline CSS and apply it via jQuery
function applyStyles(div) {

    //log the div
    console.log(div);

    //loop through the inline CSS properties applied by Google Maps API
    for (var propertyNum = 0; propertyNum < div.style.length; propertyNum++) {

        //get property and convert to camelCase
        var property = div.style[propertyNum].replace(/-([a-z])/g, function (g) { return g[1].toUpperCase(); })

        //get value
        var value = div.style[property];

        //log the property and value
        console.log(property + " = " + value);

        //apply style via jquery
        $(div).css(property, value);
    }

    //log a line break
    console.log("");

    //do the same for children of this div
    var children = $(div).children();
    for (var child = 0; child < children.length; child++) {
        applyStyles(children[child]);
    }

}
```

This is not working. None of the styles are taking effect.

Comment: When/How are you calling that function?  It likely won't work on the InfoWindow content until after the InfoWindow is open and added to the DOM (after the `domready` event fires). Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @geocodezip I have edited my question to show that I am calling the function after the `domready` event fires. Using `console.log()` I have determined that the function is taking effect after the info window is open and added to the DOM. The function does get the inline styles that Google has added to that window. Also note that I am doing this on `#map-wrapper` and every one of its descendants because the styling for the info window doesn't seem to be limited to the info window `div` itself.

Comment: @geocodezip I have now edited my question to include a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> None of the styles are taking effect.

This was not true. The styles that I was "getting" via the `style` properties of the elements were in fact being applied via the jQuery `.css()` method.

My mistake was to assume that the styles being applied by the API were limited to *inline* CSS (e.g. `<div style="background=color: #ffffff">`) when the API was also injecting *internal* CSS (e.g. `<style>div {background=color: #ffffff">}</style>`).

I noticed that the relevant `div`s all had class names starting with `gm-style-iw` (where, presumably, "gm" means Google Maps and "iw" means info window).  I searched the injected style tags and found that only one of them had these class names.

```
.gm-style .gm-style-iw{font-weight:300;font-size:13px;overflow:hidden}.gm-style .gm-style-iw-a{position:absolute;width:9999px;height:0}.gm-style .gm-style-iw-t{position:absolute;width:100%}.gm-style .gm-style-iw-t::after{background:linear-gradient(45deg,rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 51%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);box-shadow:-2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(178,178,178,.4);content:"";height:15px;left:0;position:absolute;top:0;transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(-45deg);width:15px}.gm-style .gm-style-iw-c{position:absolute;box-sizing:border-box;overflow:hidden;top:0;left:0;transform:translate(-50%,-100%);background-color:white;border-radius:8px;padding:12px;box-shadow:0 2px 7px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)}.gm-style .gm-style-iw-d{box-sizing:border-box;overflow:auto}.gm-style .gm-style-iw-d::-webkit-scrollbar{width:18px;height:12px;-webkit-appearance:none}.gm-style .gm-style-iw-d::-webkit-scrollbar-track,.gm-style .gm-style-iw-d::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece{background:#fff}.gm-style .gm-style-iw-c .gm-style-iw-d::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.12);border:6px solid transparent;border-radius:9px;background-clip:content-box}.gm-style .gm-style-iw-c .gm-style-iw-d::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal{border:3px solid transparent}.gm-style .gm-style-iw-c .gm-style-iw-d::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3)}.gm-style .gm-style-iw-c .gm-style-iw-d::-webkit-scrollbar-corner{background:transparent}.gm-style .gm-iw{color:#2c2c2c}.gm-style .gm-iw b{font-weight:400}.gm-style .gm-iw a:link,.gm-style .gm-iw a:visited{color:#4272db;text-decoration:none}.gm-style .gm-iw a:hover{color:#4272db;text-decoration:underline}.gm-style .gm-iw .gm-title{font-weight:400;margin-bottom:1px}.gm-style .gm-iw .gm-basicinfo{line-height:18px;padding-bottom:12px}.gm-style .gm-iw .gm-website{padding-top:6px}.gm-style .gm-iw .gm-photos{padding-bottom:8px;-ms-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-webkit-user-select:none}.gm-style .gm-iw .gm-sv,.gm-style .gm-iw .gm-ph{cursor:pointer;height:50px;width:100px;position:relative;overflow:hidden}.gm-style .gm-iw .gm-sv{padding-right:4px}.gm-style .gm-iw .gm-wsv{cursor:pointer;position:relative;overflow:hidden}.gm-style .gm-iw .gm-sv-label,.gm-style .gm-iw .gm-ph-label{cursor:pointer;position:absolute;bottom:6px;color:#fff;font-weight:400;text-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 0 1px 4px;font-size:12px}.gm-style .gm-iw .gm-stars-b,.gm-style .gm-iw .gm-stars-f{height:13px;font-size:0}.gm-style .gm-iw .gm-stars-b{position:relative;background-position:0 0;width:65px;top:3px;margin:0 5px}.gm-style .gm-iw .gm-rev{line-height:20px;-ms-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-webkit-user-select:none}.gm-style.gm-china .gm-iw .gm-rev{display:none}.gm-style .gm-iw .gm-numeric-rev{font-size:16px;color:#dd4b39;font-weight:400}.gm-style .gm-iw.gm-transit{margin-left:15px}.gm-style .gm-iw.gm-transit td{vertical-align:top}.gm-style .gm-iw.gm-transit .gm-time{white-space:nowrap;color:#676767;font-weight:bold}.gm-style .gm-iw.gm-transit img{width:15px;height:15px;margin:1px 5px 0 -20px;float:left}
```

I simply copied and pasted the CSS and added it to an external stylesheet. A more ideal solution would be to programmatically get the CSS and apply it via jQuery, but this will work for my purposes for now.

But even after I did this, the "x" button in the top right corner of the info window was not appearing because the image source was a data URI, which is not allowed by a strong CSP.

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%2224px%22%20height%3D%2224px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2024%2024%22%20fill%3D%22%23000000%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M19%206.41L17.59%205%2012%2010.59%206.41%205%205%206.41%2010.59%2012%205%2017.59%206.41%2019%2012%2013.41%2017.59%2019%2019%2017.59%2013.41%2012z%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M0%200h24v24H0z%22%20fill%3D%22none%22%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E%0A" style="pointer-events: none; display: block; width: 13px; height: 13px; margin: 12px;">
```

To solve this, I temporarily disabled the CSP so that I could take a screenshot of the x button. I actually took two screenshots, one for the normal symbol and one for the darkened version that appears on `mouseover`. I saved these as GIFs and stored them on the server.

I found that the `domready` event was not working as expected for the info window. My workaround was as follows:

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent("<div class='info-window'>foobar</div>");
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);

    //check to see if the info window has loaded yet
    checkForInfoWindow();
});

function checkForInfoWindow() {
    var checkForInfoWindow = setInterval(function() {
        if ($(".info-window").length) {
            styleInfoWindow();
            clearInterval(checkForInfoWindow);
        }
    }, 1);
}

function styleInfoWindow() {

    //style the "x" button
    var button = $(".info-window").parent().parent().parent().children("button");
    $(button).html("<img src='/images/x.gif'>");
    $(button).mouseover(function() {
        $(button).html("<img src='/images/x-hover.gif'>");
    });
    $(button).mouseout(function() {
        $(button).html("<img src='/images/x.gif'>");
    });

    //get divs with a class name beginning with "gm-style-iw"
    var divs = $("div[class^='gm-style-iw']");

    //for each div
    for (var div = 0; div < divs.length; div++) {

        //for each inline css property
        for (var propertyNum = 0; propertyNum < divs[div].style.length; propertyNum++) {

            //get property and convert to camelCase
            var property = divs[div].style[propertyNum].replace(/-([a-z])/g, function (g) { return g[1].toUpperCase(); })

            //get value
            var value = divs[div].style[property];

            //apply style
            divs[div].style[property] = value;
        }

    }

}
```

But the positioning of the "x" button was not quite right, because when there was a vertical scroll bar, the "x" button was practically on top of it. I solved this by adding the following to the external CSS:

```
.gm-style-iw-d{margin-top: 1rem;}
```

And voila! The info windows look like they did before I implemented the CSP.